# How to transform xml and keep newlines?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to preserve row breaks in an xml file when transforming it to html, but I cant find a way that works.

```
<meta>
    <name>Message</name>
    <value>Hi!

    I need info!

    Mr Test</value>
</meta>
```

And I use this xsl:

```
  <xsl:if test="name='Message'">
  <tr>
    <th align="left" colspan="2">Message:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="value"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:if>
```

But the new line (cr/lf) characters dissapear, and everything becomes one single line in html. Is is possible to match the cr/lf and replace them with html "<_br >", or any other method?

Comment: Are you sure the linefeeds really disappears? Linefeeds are typically ignored by an HTML parser, unless wrapped in a <pre> tag.

Comment: It almost worked with the <pre>. It did preserve/show the line breaks, but it changed the font for the <pre>-wrapped text also.

Comment: @kaze: I guess you have some reading to do on HTML in general and CSS in particular. This question actually has nothing to do with XML or XSLT. You just happen to use them for creating sub-optimal HTML, they don't cause your problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add the following template to your XSL:-

```
<xsl:template name="LFsToBRs">
    <xsl:param name="input" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($input, '&#10;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input, '&#10;')" /><br />
            <xsl:call-template name="LFsToBRs">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, '&#10;')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$input" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Now replace where select the value with a call to this template:-

```
<td colspan="2">
    <xsl:call-template name="LFsToBRs">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</td>
```

Comment: This is great, and very helpful. Unfortunately, I found that it breaks my  disable-output-escaping="yes" statement. I'm not certain where to put that now to ensure that HTML embedded in CDATA is rendered as html and not &gt; ... etc

Comment: This solution is not suitable for huge documents with a lot of line breaks. Indeed, the template is recursively called, and it comes a point where the stack overflows.

Comment: This was helpful. But I kept getting indention so i used normalize-space($input) to fix it

Answer (score 7):

Greetings, if you already have LF or CR in the source xml (looks like you have),
try putting in a  with "white-space: pre" style.

i.e:

```
<div style="white-space: pre;">
  <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed *Is it possible to match the cr/lf and replace them with html `<br>`*